# Specific KClass from Star projection collection

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm trying to build a Synchronization class to which external modules can register, but I can't make the generics part work.

External modules will register `SynchronizationBundle<SynchronizableType>` on a `Synchronizator`, which should then handle the synchronization.

```
interface Synchronizable<T : Synchronizable<T>>

object SynchronizationBundles {
    val bundles: MutableMap<KClass<*>, SynchronizableBundle<*>> = mutableMapOf()

    fun <T : Synchronizable<T>> register(kClass: KClass<T>, bundle: SynchronizableBundle<T>) {
        bundles[kClass] = bundle
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    operator fun <T: Synchronizable<T>> get(kClass: KClass<T>) : SynchronizableBundle<T> {
        return bundles[kClass] as? SynchronizableBundle<T> ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("No bundle for ${kClass.simpleName}")
    }
}
```

For example, on the *synchronize* operation, it should iterate over the registered bundles and be able to work with specific implementations of `Synchronizable<T>`. Pseudo code ahead

```
fun synchronize() {
    bundles.forEach { bundleEntry ->
        val bundle = bundles[bundleEntry.key]
        val synchronizables = bundle.api.get()

        remoteSynchronizables.forEach { remoteSynchronizable ->
            val localSynchronizable = bundle.datastore.getByPlatformId(remoteSynchronizable.platformId)

            val synchronizableToInsert = bundle.conflictStrategy.resolve(localSynchronizable, remoteSynchronizable)

            synchronizableToInsert?.let {
                bundle.datastore.insert(it.withUploadStatus(UploadStatus.COMPLETED))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that `val bundle = bundles[bundleEntry.key]` returns a `SynchronizableBundle<*>`, so I can't invoke `.conflictStrategy.resolve` because it expects a `Synchronizable<T>`

As an example, this is the `ConflictStrategy` definition. Api and Datastore follow the same pattern

```
interface ConflictStrategy<T : Synchronizable<T>>
```

Is this even possible? I'm sure I'm not the first one to try this approach.

If I could somehow invoke `val bundle = bundles[MySynchronizable::class]` I'd get a `SynchronizableBundle<MySynchronizable>`, but I haven't succeeded in doing that. Also, the Types `Synchronizator` will work with will be in external modules, so I don't even know if building a specific `KClass` would work.

Working with higher order functions would maybe make my life easier, and this Synchronizator could be type agnostic, but I haven't tried that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the following I simplified the code a bit to demonstrate how this bundle manager can be used from outside:

```
object Bundles{
    private val bundles: MutableMap<KClass<*>, Bundle<*>> = mutableMapOf()

    fun <T>  register(c: KClass<T>, b: Bundle<T>){
        bundles[c]= b
    }

    operator fun <T> get(kClass: KClass<T>) : Bundle<T> {
        return bundles[kClass] as? Bundle<T> ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("No bundle for ${kClass.simpleName}")
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Bundles.register(String::class, Bundle())
    Bundles.register(Int::class, Bundle())
    Bundles.register(Number::class, Bundle())

    val stringBundle = Bundles[String::class]
    val intBundle = Bundles[Int::class]
    val numBundle = Bundles[Number::class]
}
```

You already noticed that this works. Now, you're trying to loop the `bundles` inside your `SynchronizationBundles`. At this point you cannot know what has been added to `bundles` and thus there is not way to get the concrete instances from it. I'm afraid you have to look into other approaches.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too :(

I'll give the higher order functions a try.